# Entity Framework - specifying criteria for related records

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework. :-)
I have something similar to the following:
Master Table
------------------------------------
Id:    Name:        Detail_id:
1      MasterOne     1
2      MasterTwo     2

Details Table:
------------------------------------
Id:    Name:        Type:
1      Detail_1     1
2      Detail_2     1
3      Detail_3     2

The Details table has a flag ('Type') that differentiates between the record types.

My Master object looks like this:

> public class Master
>   {
>      public int ID { get; set; }
>      public string Name { get; set; }
>      public virtual IEnumerable`<Detail>` Details { get; set; }
>   }

My Master table needs to load its detail records but ONLY those with a flag of '1'.

My problem is that the IEnumerable Details property pulls in ALL detail records, whereas I need it to only pull in those detail records with a Type flag = 1.

Is this possible?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using EF 4.1

If you are loading only 1 `Master` record you can load filtered list of `Details` as follows.

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var master = context.Masters.Find(1);

    context.Entry(master)
        .Collection(m => m.Details)
        .Query()
        .Where(d => d.Type == 1)
        .Load();

    //do stuff with master

}
```

You can go through [Using DbContext in EF 4.1 Part 6: Loading Related Entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx) to learn more about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
var master = (ctx.Masters.Where(x => x.ID == 1)).FirstOrDefault();
var details = master.Details.Where(x=>x.Type == 1);
```